# how to start up items only when laptop plugged in

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, boot

I'm running windows 8.1 (but that shouldn't matter) on a laptop and was wondering if it would be possible to modify the startup process in a way that:

Certain programs ONLY start when you're plugged in (power) and other programs ONLY start when you're NOT plugged in.

Is this possible.. and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if there are any 3rd party utilities to do this, but Windows does have built-in mechanisms to monitor battery status.  The good news is that it makes a wealth of information about your battery available to you.  The bad news is that it doesn't make it easy for you to use it at all.

A great way to accomplish what you want is to use a script to launch your applications.  I banged out a sample script below.  Just copy/paste it into Notepad, tweak it however you want, and then **save it as a file with a .vbs extension**.  Once you have it working you can drop it in your Startup group or whatever.

**NOTE:** This script is just something I whipped up in ten minutes.  It should get you started, but I have not tested it thoroughly.  The values returned by BatteryStatus are documented on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You may have to experiment to see what value gets reported under what curcumstances.

```
Option Explicit

Const execApp1 = "application string goes here"
Const execApp2 = "example:   "c:\full\path\to.exe /arg1 /arg2"
Const execApp3 = "Use double quotes around things with spaces ""like so""."

Dim objShell :Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objWMI :Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Dim objBatteries :Set objBatteries = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Battery",,48)
Dim objBattery :Set objBattery = Nothing

Dim onACPower :onACPower = False

For Each objBattery in objBatteries
    If objItem.BatteryStatus = 2 Then   '2 is the value I got on a full battery. You may need to experiment with this.
        onACPower = True
    End If
Next

'Here's where you decide if you're on battery or AC and what to run in each case.
If onACPower = True Then objShell.Run execApp1, 0, False
If onACPower = False Then objShell.Run execApp2, 0, False
If onACPower = True Then objShell.Run execApp3, 0, False
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I hope to try this out sometime soon. In the meantime.. when the battery is full and I would unplug my computer and turn it on, wouldn't the obItem.BatteryStatus be 2 as well..?

Comment: Nevermind... your script at least got me in the right direction and I found more info elsewhere: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/04/09/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-laptop-computer-is-running-off-batteries.aspx

Comment: Ok, I have the following: (example)

Const execApp1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"""
Const execApp2 = """C:\Users\Yeppers\AppData\Roaming\SomeProgram\bin\SomeProgram.exe /systemstartup"""

It runs the first, but it doesn't run the second. It says: "The system cannot find the file specified". Why is this a problem? Is it not allowed to use Appdata?

Comment: For the second app, you have your quotation marks in the wrong spot.  It should read: `Const execApp2 = """C:\Users\Yeppers\AppData\Roaming\SomeProgram\bin\SomeProgram.exe"" /systemstartup"`  And as far as the status, 2 means AC connected, but if it were plugged in when the battery wasn't full, it might read 6 (charging). I didn't test that far when I wrote it, but I figured you'd figure it out :-)

Comment: Updated [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141215151419/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/04/09/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-laptop-computer-is-running-off-batteries.aspx) for the link in Malachi's comment that one longer works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Wes Sayeed for pointing me into the right direction, here is the final result.. Note however that programs may not be running the same as on your computer, since I used those as an example and any syntax added may not have anything to do with the programs as you know it...

```
Option Explicit

Const execApp1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"""
Const execApp2 = """C:\Users\MyProfile\AppData\Roaming\SomeProgram\bin\SomeProgram.exe"" /systemstartup"

Dim strComputer
strComputer = "."

Dim objShell :Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objWMIService :Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\wmi")
Dim colItems :Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From BatteryStatus Where Voltage > 0")
Dim objItem :Set objItem = Nothing

For Each objItem in colItems
'*    Wscript.Echo "On AC Power: " & objItem.PowerOnline
    If objItem.PowerOnline = "True" Then objShell.Run execApp1, 0, False
    If objItem.PowerOnline = "True" Then objShell.Run execApp2, 0, False
Next
```

So now 'thunderbird' and 'someprogram' run at start up ONLY when the laptop is unplugged from the power cable. To give you some more info:

```
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "Battery: " & objItem.InstanceName
    Wscript.Echo "On AC Power: " & objItem.PowerOnline
    Wscript.Echo "Battery is Discharging: " & objItem.Discharging
    Wscript.Echo "Battery is Charging: " & objItem.Charging
    Wscript.Echo "Remaining capacity: " & objItem.RemainingCapacity
Next
```

will give you more info... resulting in (when unplugged):

```
Battery: ACPI\PNP0C0A\1_0
On AC Power: False
Battery is Discharging: True
Battery is Charging: False
Remaining capacity: 41769
```

And if we then plug the computer in and try the script again we get back information similar to this:

```
Battery: ACPI\PNP0C0A\1_0
On AC Power: True
Battery is Discharging: False
Battery is Charging: True
Remaining capacity: 42273
```

So in my final script, I only checked if the AC Power was ON, no matter if the battery was charging or discharging.
(source: [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog - How Can I Tell Whether a Laptop Computer is Running Off Batteries?](https://web.archive.org/web/20141215151419/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/04/09/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-laptop-computer-is-running-off-batteries.aspx)